og:image ERROR // could not be processed as an image. It may be corrupted or may have an invalid format
This seems to be an ongoing issue with Facebook, but I cannot find any solution to it anywhere. Every other platform (Twitter, LinkedIn, Buffer) is pulling images correctly, but Facebook Sharing Debugger sporadically cannot find images and returns "could not be processed as an image. It may be corrupted or may have an invalid format."
Here is an example:
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/imagename.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1273">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="954">

What's even stranger is that some images are showing fine when others are not, for images that are uploaded, cropped, and saved in exactly the same fashion, and tags that are created identically. Robot.txt file allows access. I'm pulling my hair.
Anybody have a solution?
BUG from 1 month ago (closed by Facebook due to lack of data???)
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/782819917144617/
Community post from 3 months ago:
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/904577781133348/
Stack Overflow has similar bug from years ago, but no solutions either...
TIA!

I had the same problem and I solved it with a very simple method. I just rename the uploaded image to numeric figures. Example: old image name is (any name) to (123456) . I noticed that when uploaded images name were in Arabic, the Facebook debugger always gives an error , but only when I changed to numeric characters with or without additional English words every things were fine.

Yes, using file name in pure English. Encoding the file name like %2F.jpg doesn't help. Also, you should provide robots.txt. Clear the robots cache in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/batch if necessary.

You are not the only one with this issue.
I noticed a strange behavior: if I move the image from my subfolder to the root of the site, then it works. But as soon as I move it to a subfolder it fails. I also noticed, that if I rename the image, then debugger will show the image first time, although still complain about the image being corrupt. On next load, it's gone.
All my testing was with the same file. To me, it must be a FB issue.

If it's affected by moving the image, you may just need to allow Facebook access to the folder in your robot.txt file. Facebook now require you specifically allow them access: User-agent: facebookexternalhit

This seems to have fixed the issue I was facing. Thanks!

In case this helps someone else: Looks like the issue was a combination of not waiting long enough for Facebook to actually cache image, and og:URL needs to absolutely match the URL your page is actually going to. IE the issue has nothing to do with the image or image tag at all.
